# TypeError: JwtStrategy requires a secret or key, runs on Windows but not on Mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, passport.js

I am trying to use passport for my javascript code. However, I am getting a "JwtStrategy requires a secret or key error". I am collaborating with my friend on this. While his runs fine, mine does not and I'm not sure why. He uses windows while I use a mac, for reference.

Our code for jwt.js:

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

var User = require("./models/user");

const opts = {}
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY;

module.exports = new JwtStrategy(opts, async (jwt_payload, done) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({email: jwt_payload.email});
  if (!user) {
    return done(null, false)
  }
  return done(null, user);
})
```

The error message:

```
TypeError: JwtStrategy requires a secret or key
    at new JwtStrategy (/Users/editedUser/Desktop/frods/server/node_modules/passport-jwt/lib/strategy.js:45:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/editedUser/Desktop/frods/server/jwt.js:10:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/editedUser/Desktop/frods/server/app.js:9:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
```

Comment: It’s picking up the key from an environment variable. Do you have yours set?(JWT_SECRET_KEY)

Comment: Yep, I have it set in a .env file in the same folder as my server files.

Answer (score 2):

Update: It was a stupid mistake(?) on my part. When I saved the .env files, they were in the .crash format. It was showing up in my finder as .env, but in the command line, it was showing up as

```
.env.crash
```

I had to rename it as

```
mv .env.crash .env
```

for it to work